# abwägen vs. erwägen

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen **abwägen** und **erwägen**?

Ich habe den folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Gelbwesten erwägen Teilnahme an Europawahl (Euronews - deutsch)

Auf diese Weise verstehe ich das Verb "erwägen" - Sie wollen daran teilnehmen, aber sie schließen die Möglichkeit nicht aus, zu boykottieren.

Laut *Duden* und *linguee.de* kann man auch *einen Plan, eine Idee erwägen*. Ich schätze, das bedeutet - entscheiden darüber, ob man den Plan/die Idee akzeptieren oder ablehnen wird.

Aber was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Verben in den nachfolgenden Beispielen:

> Das Für und Wider einer Sache **erwägen** (Duden).
>
> Das Pro und Conta einer Sache **abwägen** (Duden).
>
> Vor- und Nachteile **erwägen**/**abwägen**.

Ich würde gerne andere Beispiele sehen, um den Unterschied klarer zu erkennen.

Answer (score 8):

Ich kann Janka nur zustimmen.

Beim **Erwägen** ist es typischerweise so, dass du dich fragst, ob du etwas tun oder es unterlassen sollst.

*Beispiel*

> Ein Kunde zahlt die bestellte Ware nur zum Teil und reagiert nicht auf
>   Mahnungen. Du fragst dich, ob du ihn verklagen sollst.

Beim **Abwägen** stehst du vor mehreren Alternativen, meist zwei, und überlegst dir, für welche du dich entscheiden sollst.

*Beispiel*

> Du wohnst am Meer und es ist eine Flutwelle angesagt. Du hast zwei
>   Möglichkeiten: Entweder du flüchtest oder du steigst aufs Dach. Musst
>   du abwägen.

Answer (score 4):

> <s>Für und Wieder einer Sache erwägen (Duden)</s>

Steht das wirklich so im Duden? Das kann ich nicht glauben. Hat das der Praktikant geschrieben?

> Das Für und Wider einer Sache abwägen.

Wieder ≠ Wider (zumindest heutzutage). Zudem ist der Unterschied zwischen erwägen und abwägen recht einfach zu erfassen:

> Eine Sache erwägen.
>
> Zwischen zwei Sachen abwägen.

Oder eben Für und Wider einer Sache – das sind dann zwei Sachen.

Comment: Es geht noch einfacher: _Erwägen_ ist ein Synonym von _in Betracht ziehen_.

Comment: Ja, mein Fehler - das Für und Wider einer Sache erwägen. Ich werde das korrigieren.